# How can I iterate through directories with changed files from a merge in GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

In my .gitlab-ci.yml file I have a script step that does this:

```
script:
   - python src/app1/setup.py 
   - python src/app2/setup.py
   - python src/app3/setup.py 
     ... etc
```

This is occurring in a monorepo with many different appnames.
My structure looks like this:

- src

  - app1

    - setup.py
    - misc.py
  - app2

    - setup.py
    - misc.py
  - app3

    - setup.py
    - misc.py

When a file is updated in one of the src/appname directories, I want to be able to get the appname so I can then run the above script on only that folder/directory and not have to list all of them like above. So if misc.py in app1 changed, the script would execute like this:

```
script:
   - python src/app1/setup.py
```

or if App2 was updated this would execute:

```
script:
   - python src/app2/setup.py
```

I would need to get a list of any parent directories that had files changed in them and then iterate through that list in the script. I imagine it would look something like this in gitlab-ci:

```
script:
   - python src/{APPNAME_VARIABLE}/setup.py
```

Is this possible to do in gitlab-ci?

Comment: Can you just do something like `git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`?